# Quickest distance computation between two large vectors in R

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I wish to calculate the distance between each element in one vector and each element in another vector in the quickest possible way in R. A small example is:

```
distf<-function(a,b) abs(a-b)
x<-c(1,2,3)
y<-c(1,1,1)
result<-outer(x,y, distf)
```

The issue is that my x and y are now of length 30,000 each and R crashes while trying to do this computation. And this is only doing it once, but I have to repeat the process 1000 times in a simulation study. Are there any quicker functions to be able to achieve this?

I eventually need to identify which of these distances are less than a fixed number/calliper. I will be studying many such fixed callipers eventually, therefore, I need to save all these distances, especially if the computation is so demanding. A function called caliper in the R package optmatch does this process directly, but that cannot handle such a big computation as well.

Comment: do you need all 45 million (give or take) pairwise distances at the end, or do you need some other calculation based on those distances?

Comment: I need to identify which of these distances are less than a prespecified number/calliper, replacing the ones less than a certain distance with 1's and rest with 0's. I will need all the distances as I wish to study different callipers eventually.     I have tried a function called caliper in the package optmatch that does this process directly, but it cannot handle such a big computation as well.

Comment: That information should probably be in your question.

Comment: ok, edited, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `Rcpp` version that returns an integer matrix of 1s and 0s dependent on whether each pair wide comparison is <= a threshold. On my machine it took 22.5 secs to do 30,000 by 30,000. The output matrix is a little under 7 GB in RAM though.

**fast_cal.cpp**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix fast_cal(NumericVector x, NumericVector y, double threshold) {
  const long nr=x.length();
  const long nc=y.length();
  NumericMatrix output(nr, nc);
  for (long i=0; i<nr; i++) {
    for (long j=0; j<nc; j++) {
      output(i, j) = (fabs(x(i) - y(j)) <= threshold) ? 1 : 0;
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Testing

```
library("Rcpp")
sourceCpp("fast_cal.cpp")
x <- rnorm(30000)
y <- rnorm(30000)
out <- fast_cal(x, y, 0.5)
```

Comment: That looks great, but I have never used Rcpp before, so I am just reading up on how to use Rcpp on OS X. Thank you very much; will try this solution out.

Comment: I finally figured out how to run this piece of code. It is really quick, took about 38 seconds on my system; definitely helps my situation. Thanks!